# Installing multiple instances of transmission-daemon on centos 6.5 64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, transmission, torrent

So I found this guide to installing multiple instances for ubuntu, but it doesn't seem to work for centos 6.5. Can someone point me in the right direction? I found a guide here https://www.scribd.com/doc/242365178/How-to-Run-Multiple-Instances-of-Transmission-Daemon-in-Linux-Debian-or-Ubuntu

In addition,  this is the basic commands I Was trying to run:

```
yum install transmission-daemon

/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
cp /usr/bin/transmission-daemon /usr/bin/transmission-daemon2 
cp /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon2 
cp -a /var/lib/transmission-daemon /var/lib/transmission-daemon2 
cp -a /etc/transmission-daemon /etc/transmission-daemon2 
cp /etc/default/transmission-daemon /etc/default/transmission-daemon2 
chmod 777 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon2 
chmod 777 /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon2 
chmod 777 /var/lib/transmission-daemon2  
chmod 777 /etc/transmission-daemon2 
chmod 777 /etc/default/transmission-daemon2
```

This is as far as I got as some of the copying of the files do not exist, so basically I am stuck here.

Comment: `rpm -ql transmission-daemon` to see where the files are installed from the rpm instead of the deb.

Answer (score 1):

Did some digging, thanks to the one who replied, it put me on the right track. Here's a complete guide :).

```
wget https://github.com/elijahpaul/install-transmission/raw/master/install-transmission.sh

chmod u+x install-transmission.sh

./install-transmission.sh
```

Create a user and a password. Let the script do the work for you. You will now have a transmission client running at http:// " YOUR IP ":9091
All the required files should be installed now. We just need to copy them all over for another transmission client.

```
cp -r /home/"Original Transmission Folder" /home/"Put any new user here"
```

edit ->>>>>> 
    /home/"New User"/.config/transmission/settings.json

These fields need to be changed.
    "rpc-port": 9092, (increase by 1)
    "rpc-username": "Name of New user folder", 
    "peer-port": 51414, (increase this by 1)

save the changes and permissions.

```
 chmod 777 /home/"New User"/.config/transmission/settings.json
```

Next

```
cp /etc/rc.d/init.d/transmissiond /etc/rc.d/init.d/transmissiond2
```

Edit These fields in the file /etc/rc.d/init.d/transmissiond2

```
TRANSMISSION_HOME=/home/"New User Folder"
DAEMON_USER="New USer"
NAME=transmission-daemon2
```

Next some more file copying 
    cp /usr/local/src/transmission-2.84/daemon/transmission-daemon /usr/local/src/transmission-2.84/daemon/transmission-daemon2

```
cp /usr/bin/transmission-daemon /usr/bin/transmission-daemon3
```

Lastly adding the user and setting permissions for the new folder

```
useradd "New User"
psswd "New User"
```

set a password so you can login into transmission on the 9092 port.

```
chmod 777 /home/"New User"
```

Last step is to start the transmission client up by runnng this command:
    sudo service transmissiond2 start
and to have it on always on start
    sudo chkconfig transmissiond2 on

*** If you are having trouble connecting to the ports I advise running this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9092 -j ACCEPT
```

check to see if it is active

```
iptables -L -n
```

and saving the file

```
iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables

service iptables restart
```

You can run as many as you want. Just change the user folders, ports, and transmissiond/transmission-daemon names. If anything isn't working let me know I will update.

:)

If that isnt working run:
    service iptables stop